# JSON Array - update setState for unilimited number of JSONs in array. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state where I store unlimited JSON objects.
example:

```
const [creditParams, setCreditParams] = useState([
    {
      amount: "",
      installment: "",
      insurance: "",
      commission: "",
      numOfInstallments: "",
    },
    {
      amount: "",
      installment: "",
      insurance: "",
      commission: "",
      numOfInstallments: "",
    },
  ]);
```

Users can add another object (credit calculator) by clicking on the button, and the view is generated by mapping that example array.

The data is load from input text fields

```
<TextField
                  id="installment"
                  type="number"
                  label="Installment amount:"
                  value={installment}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  helperText="How big is your installment"
                  variant="outlined"
                  index={index}
/>
```

I can't find a reasonable way to handle input here.
When I have only one object I use

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    const name = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setCreditParams({ ...creditParams, [name]: value });
  };
```

now I try

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    const name = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value;
    const index = e.target.index;
    let creditObject = creditParams[index];
    creditObject = { ...creditObject, [name]: value };
    creditParams[index] = creditObject;
    setCreditParams(creditParams);
  };
```

But that doesn't update input in text fields :(
Can you help, please?

Answer (score 0):

That part `creditParams[index] = creditObject;` is incorrect. You shouldn't modify state variable directly. Instead use `map` to find and change the right item:

```
setCreditParams(prevCreditParams => prevCreditParams.map(
  (item, itemIndex) => itemIndex === index ? creditObject : item
));
```